# How to recreate missing Team Foundation Server database?

Tags: sql-server, team-foundation-server

I've been trying out TFS 2010 Beta 2 on my local machine, or at least, had installed ready to do so. I had some issues with my MSSQL2008 server so I completely uninstalled and re-installed it and that sorted it.

However, I'm now in limbo with TFS. I have the software installed, but it has none of the SQL databases installed that go with it.

I had no data and am not precious about how to go about it. I figure completely uninstalling and re-installing might be an idea and will most likely fix it (repair didn't work). Is there a quicker way? Is there a command line utility that I can run, or a SQL script to recreate it all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a SQL backup (or the MDF and LDF files) I think you will need to re-install.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsprerelease/thread/2836afce-2075-4f0d-b50c-dca8c1add929